# Variables inside Javascript injection [webview]

Tags: java, android

So I have this line of code:

```
myWebview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_confirm_email').value='example@gmail.com';void(0);");
```

for the value inside the javascript injection (example@gmail.com), I want to use a variable written inside my onCreate method. Is this possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Comment: Please learn string concatenation in JavaScript. This is very simple. Google it.

Comment: Directly: No. Indirectly: You should use `JavaScript Interface` to introduce a bridge between Java side and JavaScript side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that.

```
String emailSTR = "example@gmail.com";
myWebview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('join_confirm_email').value='"+emailStr+"';void(0);");
```